# Extract Between Parts of a String

Tags: r, extract, gsub

I have a string of names in the following format:

```
names <- c("Q-1234-1", "Q-1234-2", "Q-1234-1-8", "Q-1234-2-8")
```

I am trying to extract the single digit after the second hyphen. There are instances where there will be a third hyphen and an additional digit at the end of the name. The desired output is:

```
1, 2, 1, 2
```

I assume that I will need to use sub/gsub but am not sure where to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the pattern of zero or more characters that are not a `-` (`[^-]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `-` followed by zero or more characters that are not a `-` followed by a `-` and the number that follows being captured as a group.  In the replacement, we use the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`)

```
as.integer(sub("^[^-]*-[^-]*-(\\d).*", "\\1", names))
#[1] 1 2 1 2
```

---

Or this can be modified to

```
as.integer(sub("^([^-]*-){2}(\\d).*", "\\2", names))
#[1] 1 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using `stringr`

```
library("stringr")
names <- c("Q-1234-1", "Q-1234-2", "Q-1234-1-8", "Q-1234-2-8")
output = str_split_fixed(names, pattern = "-", n = 4)[,3]
```